# Why nav_menu_css_class doesn't work with apply_filters?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, css

I was trying to add css class to nav items.

The documented function call in [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) was

```php
apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', string[] $classes, WP_Post $item, stdClass $args, int $depth )
```

But I tried adding the following to functions.php in my child theme doesn't work.

```php
apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', ['nav-item']);
```

But the adding the following to functions.php works as expected.

```php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', fn () => ['nav-item']);
```

Why do add_filter works but not apply_filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's not what `apply_filters()` does. You'll even see the usage guide and examples at [your link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) all use `add_filter()`. Also see [the official docs on Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/).

Using `apply_filters()` makes a value filterable. `add_filter()` is used to filter a filterable value by passing a function that does the filtering.

*WordPress* uses `apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', ...`, which allows you to use `add_filter()` to modify its value. So if you want to modify the nav menu CSS classes, you need to add a filter, with `add_filter()`.

The reason `apply_filters()` is shown in the docs [you linked](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) is because it's showing how that filter was originally defined. Not how to use it.